# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI.I have deployed project as maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have already searched for a solution in many threads but nothing worked for me.Whenever I typed this URL http://localhost:8080/springMVC/web-app/WEB-INF/index.html it is showing following error.

Aug 07, 2016 7:21:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springMVC/web-app/WEB-INF/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MyDemo'

Here is my **web.xml** file.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyDemo</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-  class>

<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyDemo</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**servlet-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.controller.*"></context:component-scan>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>

<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

</bean>

</beans>
```

**MyDemoController.java**

```
package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller

public class MyDemoController {

@RequestMapping(value="/index") 
public String getqoute(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("random","To be");
    return "quote";
}



}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Link which you are using to access your web application looks confusing to me. http://localhost:8080/springMVC/web-app/WEB-INF/index.html - Do you really need web-app and WEB-INF in your link? Please try - http://localhost:8080/springMVC/index.html.

Comment: @asg When I try  [link](http://localhost:8080/springMVC/index.html) it is showing HTTP 404 error and in console it is showing only 'MyDemo' initialization is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base-package="com.demo.controller.*">

change it to base-package="com.demo.controller">

also use
@RequestMapping("/index")